# I tried to make the bot to make that only certain roles can use the !sendmessage command

Tags: python, discord.py

```
allowed_role_id = (---) # replace with the ID of the allowed role

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})')

@bot.command(name='sendmessage')
@commands.has_any_role(discord.Object(id=allowed_role_id))
async def send_message(ctx, *, message: str):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if not member.bot:
            dm_channel = await member.create_dm()
            sent_message = await dm_channel.send(message)
            await sent_message.add_reaction("✅")
            await sent_message.add_reaction("❌")
            await sent_message.add_reaction("")

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    member = bot.get_user(payload.user_id) # Using the user_id here
    if member == bot.user:
        return

    guild = bot.get_guild(1077548297037819985) # Since this is in a dm, use the integer value for your guild.
    member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)

    if message.author != bot.user:
        return

    log_channel = bot.get_channel(1095793300184764477)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Reaction Log", color=0x00ff00)
    embed.add_field(name="User", value=f"{member.mention} ({member.id})", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Reaction", value=payload.emoji.name, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Roles", value=" ".join([role.mention for role in member.roles]), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Nickname", value=member.nick, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Joined At", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), inline=True)
    await log_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

I expect that only this role id can be using the command, but I tried to make it and it still doesn't work, I couldn't find what I'm doing wrong.

**Can someone answer it with the changed format and code, and tell me what was i doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`commands.has_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_role) documentation (which you can use instead of [`commands.has_any_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role) since you only want to check for one [`Role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#role)), you should use the role id directly instead of wrapping it inside an [`Object`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#object).

Modified code:

```py
allowed_role_id = (---) # replace with the ID of the allowed role

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})')

@bot.command(name='sendmessage')
@commands.has_role(allowed_role_id)
async def send_message(ctx, *, message: str):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if not member.bot:
            dm_channel = await member.create_dm()
            sent_message = await dm_channel.send(message)
            await sent_message.add_reaction("✅")
            await sent_message.add_reaction("❌")
            await sent_message.add_reaction("")

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    member = bot.get_user(payload.user_id) # Using the user_id here
    if member == bot.user:
        return

    guild = bot.get_guild(1077548297037819985) # Since this is in a dm, use the integer value for your guild.
    member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)

    if message.author != bot.user:
        return

    log_channel = bot.get_channel(1095793300184764477)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Reaction Log", color=0x00ff00)
    embed.add_field(name="User", value=f"{member.mention} ({member.id})", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Reaction", value=payload.emoji.name, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Roles", value=" ".join([role.mention for role in member.roles]), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Nickname", value=member.nick, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Joined At", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), inline=True)
    await log_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: it works perrfectly, saved my life thanks, i thought when i put answered question i thought it identified that your answer meant that you answered my question